# Firebase Realtime Database and Flutter - Snapshot has no data

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I try to implement the Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter and I want to display updated values in realtime. I try to achieve this with a `StreamBuilder`.

**StreamBuilder Code**

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: GuestbooksDatabase().getAllGuestbooksSync().asStream(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data.length) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(snapshot.data[index].title);
          });
    }
  }),
```

**The stream function**

```
Future<List<Guestbook>> getAllGuestbooksSync() async {
    List<Guestbook> guestbooks = [];
    databaseRef.onValue.listen((event) async {
      var dataSnapshot = event.snapshot;

      if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
        dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value) async {
          Guestbook guestbook = await Guestbook.fromJson(value);
          guestbook.setId(key);
          guestbooks.add(guestbook);
        });

        await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
        print(guestbooks); // Result: All Instances of Guestbook
        return guestbooks;
      }
    });
  }
```

I only see the `CircularProgressIndicator()` what means that the snapshot has no data.
What's the issue there?

Comment: what does it mean !snapshot.data.length

Comment: Fires when the length of snapshot data is <= 0..

Comment: Did you check already which of the two conditions in `snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data.length` is true? Because the latter means that the read completed, but resulted in no data, while the former means that the read never completed. Also: did you check the output of the app for errors/warnings?

Comment: If I `print(snapshot.data)` in the StreamBuilder the result is `null`. So there is no data and the `!snapshot.hasData` condition is true.

Comment: PS: No errors, no warnings. From the `getAllGuestbooksSync()` I get the right output, but the `StreamBuilder` does not knows it... :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`StreamController`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.1/dart-async/StreamController-class.html) for this.

Create a new controller -

```dart
final StreamController streamController = StreamController<List>.broadcast();
```

Convert `Future<List>` to `void` type for your `getAllGuestbooksSync()` function and return nothing.

**It can and will be called in `initState()` -**

```dart
void getAllGuestbooksSync() {
    List<Guestbook> guestbooks = [];
    databaseRef.onValue.listen((event) async {
      var dataSnapshot = event.snapshot;

      if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
        dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value) async {
          Guestbook guestbook = await Guestbook.fromJson(value);
          guestbook.setId(key);
          guestbooks.add(guestbook);
        });

        print(guestbooks); // Result: All Instances of Guestbook

        streamController.add(guestbooks); // Adding list to the stream
      }
    });
}
```

In your `StreamBuilder` use -

```dart
stream: streamController.stream,
```

Comment: This works if I use the function in the same file with the StreamBuilder, right? I'm using the `getAllGuestbooksSync()` in a separate file which I'm using as database service. This is just a class without Stateless widget or StateFul Widget. So there is no `initState`. Will this also work?

Comment: You can use different controllers in separate files and then you can pass the controller object from one class to another (on file to another). It should work like that.

Comment: Is not working. The log shows permanently `flutter: AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null)`

Comment: if you can link a sample code, then it will be helpful to see what's going wrong and where